# Mockito doReturn if method of a object with certain class is called

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, mockito

If I have a object MyObject, I want to return some value if certain method of that object is called. For example something like this:

```
doReturn(someValue).when(Mockito.any(MyObject.class)).getSomeValue();
```

I have tried it like that, but it does not works :

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NullInsteadOfMockException: 
Argument passed to when() is null!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `Mockito.mock(MyObject.class)` to create a mock of your object.

Currently you're using Mockito#any which is a parameter matcher used to define behavior on a mock when a stubbed method is called for *any* given parameter.

```
@Test
public void testMock() throws InterruptedException {
    MyObject myObjectMock = Mockito.mock(MyObject.class);
    doReturn(2).when(myObjectMock).getSomeValue();

    System.out.println(myObjectMock.getSomeValue()); // prints 2
}

private class MyObject {
    public int getSomeValue() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, this example of yours works, but in my case I guess I have to add something additional since it return no value.

Comment: @mirzak I do not quite get you, can you give an example?

Comment: This solution was correct, my object was being overridden by something not related.

Comment: I just had to set it to my field using ReflectionTestUtils.

ReflectionTestUtils.setField(this.someService, "myField", mock);

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use Mockito annotations:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class YourTestClass {
  @Mock 
  MyObject myObjectMock
```

saves you from manually mocking that object within your setup or test methods.

Comment: This is a most better solution since you can use the mocked object (myObjectMock here) in mutliple test.
In my project we use @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) instead of @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)

Comment: You can declare a field without the annotation, but then you have to instantiate the mock manually in some @Before method. Note that ExtendWith is JUnit 5, and this answer was written before JUnit5 was available.